# how to search for a particular paragraph in a text file using java

Tags: java

I've a text file with a lot of content in it. I found out ways as to how to search for a word in the text file. But I've an address which has to be searched, and you all know that an address has multiple lines (can be considered as a paragraph) and thats when the problem comes.

How do I give the whole address as input for searching? when I give only one line of the address, i'm able to find the string in the text file since i use nextLine() which reads line by line. Is there a way I can give the whole address as input and search it in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try what @Oleksi said !. However I would advice to use a `StringBuffer` instead of `String`.

Something like below should work...

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:/Shashank/random.txt")));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String address =  "line1\nline2\nline3";

        while(br.ready())
        {
            sb.append(br.readLine());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        if(sb.indexOf(address)>=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Address found");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole file into a string, and then try to find your multi-line address string in that file string. This is efficient since you don't have to perform many file I/O operations, and it will work because [String.indexOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to find strings with newline characters in them.